# How do I find duplicates within a database and how do I execute a response?

Tags: python, sqlite

My program shows a search bar for a manager to search for players in a team, i have it so that my program returns "found" when the database finds the search item in the database, however, in the event that more than one players have the same first name, last name or username I need to notify the manager to be more specific in their search, this is because if successful the search will show a page with all that specific user's stats.

i have tried using the COUNT function in sqlite3 however, i haven't been able to find a good explanation online which tells you how to establish duplicates and then act upon the information.

[Code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irxdx.png)

Comment: Don't post text as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the result of the fetchall `results = cursor.fetchall()` then you can check for via `len(results) > 1` and report the duplicates. And you don't need to execute a second query.

Note that if you are executing a query and only expect 0 or 1 result use fetchone rather than fetchall. Even then one can check for a second result by calling fetchone again.